# Add a subview to MasterView of UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I need to add a subview to left part of `UIViewController`, which shows the user that there is something near the left part of screen, when masterview is hidden(in portrait orientation). And this view must move with left part of `UISplitView`. Something like the view with arrow in these two images. (Sorry for the russian interface)
http://s2.uploads.ru/8EHJI.png
http://s2.uploads.ru/NhEam.png
But my problem is that when I try to add such a view, it clips to bounds of masterview and is not visible when masterview is hidden. I think, I'm doing it wrong and there is an easy way to do this.

**Update:** I've tried to make some hack like:

```
-(void) clipToBoundsRecursive:(UIView *)someView
{
    NSLog(@"%@", someView);
    someView.clipsToBounds = NO;
    for (UIView *v in someView.subviews)
    {
        [self clipToBoundsRecursive:v];
    }
}
```

and send it to view of `splitviewcontroller`.

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[self clipToBoundsRecursive:splitViewController.view];
```

It takes effect at first time (subviews outside the masterview's bounds shows, but after first show/hide animation they disappears and don't appear even if I call this method again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like your app could benefit from [PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController).

Comment: @Padavan I beleive you can still use Storyboards. You just have to do *some* setting up in your App Delegate. I use it, it's quite simple.

Answer (score 6):

You can add the view directly to the window's `view`, though you will have to manually manage its position depending on when the device rotates.  Views added to the `window.view` will appear above the `rootViewController.view`.

Comment: But how can I synchronise it's position with moving masterView in portrait orientation?

Comment: You could actually add it to masterView's view (as a subview) and then turn off `masterView.clipsToBounds` to allow drawing outside its bounds.

Comment: It does't works. Maybe I need to change clipToBounds property of splitViewController.view, but it is undocumented UILayoutContainerView.

Answer (score 3):

I have described here a **simple Logic** for you: (*how to add a `UIView` in `Window` and call it from your master or detail view* )

Create `UIView` in `#import "AppDelegate.h"` ,

```
- (void) CreateViewInWindow
{
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 780)];// set as u wish
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // I have added myView to the Window with a specific animation , your can give animation as you like. :)
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve // change to whatever animation you like
                    animations:^ { [self.window addSubview:myView]; }
                    completion:nil];
}
```

Here create a simple  `UIButton` in the `DetailViewController.m` file  (*You can put the code in either of the files, `DetailViewController.m` OR `MasterViewController.m`*)

```
UIButton *btnShowView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btnShowView addTarget:self action:@selector(btnShowViewTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnShowView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 30, 174, 35);
//[btnLoginInner setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LoginBut.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btnShowView];
```

In button tapped method, write code for calling `UIView`  from `AppDelegate`, and also **don't  forget** to add `#import "AppDelegate.h"`  in `DetailViewController.m`,

```
-(void)btnShowViewTapped:(UIButton *) Sender
{
    AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [del performSelector:@selector(CreateViewInWindow) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```

Above code is a simple logic for your problem, It might be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This may be helpful if I can detect moving of masterView of SplitView in portrait orientation and can move my view on UIWindow synchronously with it. And this is a problem. Do you have any idea how to do it? UISplitViewControllerDelegate Protocol can't help me.

Comment: this is work if need to change only animation of uiview.. try with my code and change masterView instand of UIView

Answer (score 1):

Try with deselecting auto layout option in identity and type pan if you are using nib otherwise set autoresizing mask to view that currently clipping. I believe it will solve the issue